# Why the lightbox doesn´t close on click outside of the content container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a Lightbox. If I would close the pop up window by clicking on a button, it works well, but if I want to close it by clicking outside of the content container, it doesn't work.

Outside of the content container, I've added another container with a black opacity.

This way, I've added a class on the outside container. When click happened on the content container, it should be removed.

```
var appendthis = ("the div container look over JsFiddle");

$('a[data-modal-id]').click(function (e) {
    $(window).resize();
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#' + modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());
});

$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function () {
    $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(".modal-overlay").remove();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ljmxj8ue/

**Edit 19.11.15: Question:** Close by click outside of contant container don´t stop Youtube Video just on button click and cause this error: "Cannot read property 'stopVideo' of undefined".
JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this code (and add the first line):

```
$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").unbind('click'); // Prevents multiple bindings
$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
  $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(".modal-overlay").remove();
  });
});
```

at the end of `$('a[data-modal-id]').click`. It was not running before because the element did not exist when you assigned `$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrGarretto/97dns8u5/

Comment: It's not a perfect solution as 'click' will be assigned multiple times to `.js-modal-close` when you close / open that several times, you've to unbind the click event as well before assigning it.

Comment: Ups, you were right, now it works thank you very much.

Comment: @MrGarretto i have now another problem with this solution :(. I can stop the video by click outside the contant container just on the close button. Got this message: "Cannot read property 'stopVideo' of undefined"

Comment: ups: I **can´t** stop the video by click outside just on the button

Comment: @MrGarretto Look there [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/5/) it gives this error written before.

Comment: Because it seems to work correctly when you remove the following lines:

`player.stopVideo();`
`player.seekTo(0);`

It must be some error you made in setting up the `player` object. I have never used the Youtube API before, so sadly I cannot help you on this since I do not know enough about it.

Comment: @MrGarretto Yeah the code should work because if i close over button there is no error just if i click outside :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to assign a 'click' event to element which doesn't exist on it's invocation.

See this fiddle, I've fixed the issue for you by using

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljmxj8ue/1/

```
$(document).on('click',".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay", function() {
```

Instead of:

```
$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function () {
```

By binding the click on document - it'll listen to any clicks on the DOM and check if clicked element has got classes specified above, if yes - it'll trigger function.

Comment: Attaching delegate events to the document isn't recommended at all. Since all .live() events are attached at the document element, events take the longest and slowest possible path before they are handled

Comment: Totally agree with you, it's not the best solution. @MrGarretto provided best one for this problem.